# Question about validity of an MCMC algorithm

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, algorithms, latent-variable

Let suppose I want to sample from the posterior distribution of $X_1,X_2|y$ using an MCMC algorithm and let indicate with $X_i^t$ the value of $X_j$ at the $t-$th iterations.

I want to know if the following algorithm samples from the target distribution:

- Sample  $X_1^t$ from  the distribution of $X_1|X_2^{t-1},y$
- Sample  $X_2^t$ from  the distribution of $X_2|X_1^{t},X_3^{t-1},y$
- Sample  $X_3^t$ from  the distribution of $X_3|X_1^{t},X_2^{t},y$

where $X_3$ is a suitable variable that makes the sample of $X_2$ easier.

A reference is highly appreciated.

EDIT:

I did some simulations and it seems to work

Comment: It would certainly be correct if $X_1 |X_2, X_3 = X_1 |X_2$. Is that true?

Comment: it is not true.